# Central heat ducts(the ends that are attached to registers) in attic not securely attached to attic floor/room ceiling. How to secure?

Tags: hvac, attic, ducts

When I removed the registers in the ceiling of our house I noticed that the ducting in the ceiling was totally loose. They are not secured in any way. The two screws of the register was what was holding them in place.

What is the proper way to secure those final duct connections (the ones that the register is attached to) in the attic? Screw them down to the attic floor?

We have flexible ducting. The end of the duct is attached to rigid pieces.

Comment: Do the ducts need to be secured? I have seen runs of flex duct just lying across the ceiling joists.

Comment: What kind of ducting do you have--rigid metal, flex duct, of a combination? I see here that the best practice is to use flex for straight runs and rigid for changes in direction and maybe to allow stretching the flex taut. http://www.energyvanguard.com/blog/57709/How-to-Install-Flex-Duct-Properly

Comment: Flex ducting with rigid ends that the registers are connected to